# Solving System of Boundary Value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The boundary value problem: $$y'' + Q(t)y = f(t)$$
satisfying $$Ay(a) +By(b) = g$$
where A, B and Q are the matrices of order n.
After calculation, we can get the form of solution will be 
$$y(x) = -(A+B)^{-1}\left[\int_x^bB \cdot f(s)ds + \int_a^xA \cdot f(s)ds\right]$$
$$= \int_a^xD^{-1}A \cdot f(s)ds - \int_x^b D^{-1}B \cdot f(s)ds$$
where $D=A+B$
$$= \int_a^bG(x,s) \cdot f(s)ds$$
and $$G(x,s) = \begin{cases}D^{-1}A \text{ if } x >s \\ -D^{-1}B \text{ if } x < s\end{cases}$$
So, we used the Green function to get the solution of boundary value system. 
My question is what happened if the system is solvable, but $D$ is not invertible ?